# Should we use -moz-border-radius attribute these days?

Tags: html, firefox, css

I am using the [W3C CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to validate CSS and it returned the following error:

> Property -moz-border-radius-bottomleft doesn't exist : 5px

My question is, do we need it anymore, as modern browsers seem to understand `border-bottom-left-radius` et al.

Here is the complete CSS:

```
height: 160px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
background: transparent url(../images/search-box-repeat-small.png) repeat;
```

Comment: Did you try to use the common W3C property and remove the `-moz-border-radius-bottomleft` ?
Though you should keep it for older browsers that don't understand the new w3c norms. It's all about the public you expect on your website.

Comment: If you've going to use a browser specific experimental property … why limit yourself to `-moz` and ignore `-o`, `-webkit`, and `-ms`?

Comment: And don't bother attempting to validate prefixed properties - they'll never be valid because they're outside of the standard.

Comment: +1 for actually using the CSS validation service :)

Comment: @Depado my point here is, that CSS validation gives me an error on -moz-border.. there is no difference if i keep it or remove it. these css have been there for quite some time , so i decided to ask the community, if its -mox, -webkit are even useful anymore

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox understands the standardized `border-*-radius` properties [starting from version 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Firefox_4_for_developers#Renamed_CSS_properties).

If you're going to specify an equal radius for all four corners, and you're not interested in supporting Firefox < 4.0 and other older browsers, you may as well reduce your staggering **eight border radius declarations** to a single one:

```
height: 160px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: transparent url(../images/search-box-repeat-small.png) repeat;
```

If you need to support Firefox 3.6 and older, you will still need the prefixed property, but specifying one for every corner is still just asking for trouble:

```
height: 160px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: transparent url(../images/search-box-repeat-small.png) repeat;
```

Note also that unprefixed properties should come *last* in a rule, so browsers that support the unprefixed properties will use it for best standards conformance.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Yes, vendors do implement prefixed properties in non-conforming ways, because there is nothing in the spec that says they can't. See the [Gecko notes for `-moz-border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius#Gecko_notes) for details on what changed after Mozilla dropped the prefix.</sub>

Comment: If you have such arcane requirements as having to support Firefox all the way back to version 2, I suggest leaving out `-moz-border-radius` because it is a pixelated monstrosity in that version.

Comment: Also, the prefixed property will be going away as of Firefox 13.

Comment: well you have said what i needed.. the thing is, rounded corners dont work in IE,so i kinda dont care if they work in older mozilla browsers as well ;). thanks or the help.. i think i can start removing them ..

Answer (score 2):

Well, a lot of people insist on supporting IE6, so yes you should support the older versions of Firefox that only had -moz-border-radius.

Oh wait, Firefox users are *so* much smarter than IE users, so they know how to update. Well, guess you don't need it then.

Really, it's up to you. If you want to keep it, then do so. There's no real downside other than a little extra bandwidth (that shouldn't be a problem if you cache properly), so why not?

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox I personally don't see the need for this vendor prefix. Most modern browsers support the border-radius property as-is.

You can check this website for browser support:
http://caniuse.com/border-radius

Answer (score 0):

For modern versions of firefox no..

But for backward compatibility you need them (*pre 4.0*)

Have a look at [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) as well to automatically handle all prefixes for all (*almost*) browsers

Answer (score 0):

vendor properties must be wroten before nonvendor properties
like this

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
   -moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* IE9 */
     -o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
        transform: rotate(7.5deg);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: because of properties order in question